# Create a new array of boolean values by comparing two arrays with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, compare, javascript-objects

I have a question about creating JavaScript arrays. Here's what I want to do.

I have **two arrays**. Each array has object(s) in them.

The **first array** has *exactly* 5 objects, each with a key/value pair (id/name). This array will **ALWAYS** have 5 objects.

Here's what it looks like...

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "AnalyticalAdmin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "SystemAdministrator"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "CaseworkSTRTechLeader"
    }
]
```

The **second array** will have *either*...

1. no objects,
2. 4 or less objects,
3. exactly 5 objects.

In the example below, the second array only has *one* of the 5 objects in the first array...

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    }
]
```

I need to create a **third array** that has *exactly* 5 boolean values that are determined by comparing the first two arrays.

For example, based on the first two arrays above, the third array would be...

```
[false, false, true, false, false]
```

The reason the third array would look like this is because "AdminReviewer" is the *third object* in the first array, so the *third boolean value* in the third array would be true (since it's a match).

But because the first, second, fourth, and fifth objects in the first array *do not exist* in the second array, their boolean equivalent in the third array would be false.

To accomplish this, I know I need to either do a *compare* function on the first two arrays to create the third array (of booleans) or I need to run a *for loop* on the first array, comparing it to the second array to create the third array (of booleans).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done as follows:

```
const filterStrings = filterArray.map(o => JSON.stringify(o));
const result = baseArray.map(o => filterStrings.includes(JSON.stringify(o)));
```

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
const baseArray = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "AnalyticalAdmin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "SystemAdministrator"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "CaseworkSTRTechLeader"
    }
];

const filterArray = [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    }
];

const filterStrings = filterArray.map(o => JSON.stringify(o));
const result = baseArray.map(o => filterStrings.includes(JSON.stringify(o)));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you show me how I would convert an array of booleans back to an array of objects like the second array above?

For example, let's say I have this array of booleans from the code you gave me above... 

`[false, true, true, false, false]`

 That would be the _equivalent_ of... 

`[ { "id": 2, "name": "Analyst" }, { "id": 4, "name": "AdminReviewer" } ]` since those two objects are the second and third objects in the **baseArray** array above. How would I convert the array of booleans **back** to that array of objects?